# Is there an API to *change* Firebase Remote Config values?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Firebase console support easy way to configure remote configuration parameter.

In our app we have remote configuration different per user, and those configuration are set on our own web portal.

Is there any API by which I can push configs from my own portal to Firebase remote config server and then use remote config lib on android app to get new configurations?

Comment: Thanks for trying Firebase Remote Config. There is no API to change configuration values at the moment.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how about an option to upload a config file? So we could build a simple key/value json file on our machine and manually upload it to the firebase console. 
I'm currently exploring the possibility and utility of managing all our apps strings with RemoteConfig. The actual translations are managed with a different internal tool and it would be great if we could run a script that would build a json we can upload to firebase.

Comment: There is now a REST API to get and change Firebase Remote Config values. Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49262738/5861618)

Comment: Link to Remote Config REST API : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/announcing-remote-config-rest-api.html

Answer (score 11):

This feature is available in [Firebase Remote Config REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest)

Comment: Has it moved out of the list or still on it? Would be a very nice feature!

Comment: This is really a key thing because it would allow automated changes of configuration on a period basis, event or after a specific check

Comment: It would in fact not only be a nice feature, but it is essential - there has to be a way to export and import the values from a remote config list, otherwise bigger lists are unmanageable.

Comment: We now have an API for Remote Config - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/announcing-remote-config-rest-api.html

Comment: Did any Masters make the sample to use Rest API? I spent a day to do but I'm still getting many issues.

Comment: This example project from Google shows how to use the Remote Config REST API this on the server side with the Admin SDK: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/remote-config-diff/functions/index.js

Answer (score 4):

Yes! As of March 2018 there is now a [REST API](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/announcing-remote-config-rest-api.html) available for you to add or update values in the Remote Config service.

You can use this to either create your own custom front-ends for managing your remote config values, import Remote Config values from elsewhere, or add support to have your Remote Config values change dynamically based on something that might be happening on your server (or even a cron job).  Documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest).

Answer (score 0):

Check the official Google API [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/google/firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com).