# Firebase Remote Config Changes with Firebase Realtime Database for A/B testing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

**My question is specifically for A/B testing**

I have a set of strings stored in firebase database. I want to manipulate the data for A/B testing. One way would be to store two strings in Firebase Database. e.g

String A and String B. Then let say the remote config value be true then show String B or else string A.

Is this the way to go forward? Or should I store all the data in the remote config for A/B testing?

Answer (score 1):

Once you store the values in the database, there is no automatic way to pass then to Remote Config.

This is because there is currently no API to configure the values for users in Remote Config and A/B Testing. The only way to configure these is through the Firebase console.

Note that adding such an API is being investigated, so you might want to sign up for the [Firebase alpha program](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/firebasealphaprogram/) to see if there is an EAP going on. But as usual: no promises and no timelines on whether and when this may land.

Also see:

- [Is there an API to *change* Firebase Remote Config values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374232/is-there-an-api-to-change-firebase-remote-config-values)
- [Firebase Rest api for remote config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304938/firebase-rest-api-for-remote-config)

Comment: Note that there is now a REST API as of March 2018: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49265198/4816918